# Name of matrix operation of [ A[0] dot B[0], A[1] dot B[1] ] from 2x2 matrices A, B

Tags: matrices, inner-products, computer-algebra-systems

Please advise how this matrix operation is called, and what is the numpy operation for it. `np.inner`, `np.dot` does not create dot products from 2x2 matrices.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the diagonal of the [matrix product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) $AB$, which can be obtained in NumPy using [numpy.diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) and [numpy.matmul](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

For example

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix('0 1 2; 3 4 5')
B = np.matrix('0 -3; -1 -4; -2 -5');
np.diagonal(np.matmul(A,B)) # or (A*B).diagonal()
```

yields

```
array([ -5, -50])
```

However, this does compute the off-diagonal entries of the matrix product as well and hence isn't very efficient. Describing the entries of your resulting vector as
$$
v_i = \sum_j a_{ij} b_{ji}
$$
you can obtain the same result more efficiently using [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) as

```
np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A, B)
```